# Удобный фреймворк для юнит-тестирования C99?

Tags: windows, юнит-тесты, c, тестирование

Перепробовал несколько фреймворков для юнит-тестирования C (CuTest, cmockery, CUnit, FCTX, ещё что-то). На всех них надо писать жутко громоздкий код, плюс проделывать множество лишних телодвижений вроде регистрации сьютов. Я понимаю, что всё это естественным образом проистекает из самой природы языка C. Но неужели никто до сих пор не придумал что-нибудь человеческое? Я даже готов заплатить. Вроде есть что-то коммерческое, но я не в курсе цен и возможностей. Сто долларов отдам без боли. Больше - вряд ли. Я всего лишь фрилансер.

В качестве компилятора (и интерпретатора, что бывает ещё чаще) использую TinyCC. Платформа - Windows (и только она). Не хотелось бы ставить другой компилятор, особенно C++. А то я слышал такой совет - использовать GoogleTest, он умеет тестировать C, но нужен компилятор C++. Конечно, если реально не будет другого выхода... Но тогда уж лучше Objective-C.

Comment: я посмотрел на FCTX - думаю, за пару дней бы написал на питоне/перле скритп, который бы на вход получал что то вида

    тестсьют1
      тесткейс1 -тестим х
        strcmp("xxx", "xxx") == 0

    тестсьют2
      тесткейс2
        strcmp("xx", "xxxx") == 0
      тесткейс3
        strcmp("rew", "rew") == 0


а на выходе давал готовый с-код. Потом делается команда prove, которая ещё и скомпилит и запустит.

Если Вы хорошо знаете с (любой другой любимый язык), то Вам не проблема такое написать самостоятельно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GoogleTest хороший совет, тем более внешне тест выглядит как программа на С, если не юзать шибко крутые фичи.

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

TEST (SquareRootTest, PositiveNos) { 
    EXPECT_EQ (18.0, square-root (324.0));
    EXPECT_EQ (25.4, square-root (645.16));
    EXPECT_EQ (50.3321, square-root (2533.310224));
}
```

Ну а так еще есть [Check](http://check.sourceforge.net/) и [Unity](https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch/Unity). Я пользуюсь вторым, поскольку он подходит для embedded систем.

**UPD:** Про Unity

Ничего кроме компилятора С не нужно, берем просто 7 файликов и добавляем в проект

```
unity_fixture.c
unity_fixture.h
unity_fixture_internals.h
unity_fixture_malloc_overrides.h
unity.c
unity.h
unity_internals.h
```

Но Unity не решает проблему автоматического подключения тестов (Обычно есть два места где можно "забыть" подключить группу или тест). Подробно можно почитать в книге Test Driven Development for Embedded C.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что для Unity нужен Ruby?

Comment: Обновил ответ, нужен только C.

Comment: Спасибо, но тогда совершенно непонятно, в чём его преимущество. Есть фреймворки, которые состоят из одного файла, и подключаются тесты проще. Вот, например, из недавно найденного - http://www.lingua-systems.com/unit-testing/sput-framework/tutorial.html

Comment: @VadimTukaev, Вы уверны, что все эти инструменты стоят зараченного на них времени?

У меня сложилось впечатление (сам "в бою" не пробовал), что легко тестируются простые штуки (типа `sqrt`), с более сложными придется тщательно проверять а то ли мы тестируем, ну а с совсем сложными (например, тестирование автоматического восстановления сетевых соединений с контрольной точки или тестирование реального интерактива (GUI) с человеком) -- вообще не понятно, как построить тестовую систему и как это описать.

Comment: Уверен. Основная польза от них как раз в том, что они способствуют тому, что программист разбивает свою программу на "простые штуки типа sqrt".

Тестирование интерактива - совсем другой вопрос. Не надо смешивать.

Понемногу дозреваю до идеи сделать свой фреймворк. Наработки уже есть. Может, сегодня уже доделаю. Не знаю только, куда выложить. Системы контроля версий я не использую, так что желательно просто аплоад файла сделать. Идея в основе моего фреймворка настолько проста, что никому, похоже, не приходила в голову... А я с десяток фреймворков исследовал. У всех есть фатальные недостатки. :

Comment: [я дико извиняюсь](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA)

Comment: @VadimTukaev, хорошо если придумали удобную штуку. Только сами сначала оттестируйте (и напишите побольше примеров о разъяснений для бестолковых, как с ней надо работать).

А выложить файл (без CVS) можно на pastebin.com, опубликовать можно здесь в разделе "ИССЛЕДОВАНИЯ" (только сначала прямо на ХК в виде вопроса анонсируйте, а то в исследования (IMHO) мало кто регулярно заглядывает).

Давайте, попробуем Ваше творение.

Comment: Fike, именно это я и имел в виду, потому и поставил смайлик.

Вот, это мой первый опыт. Это не тот фреймворк, который я имел в виду! Но зато он уже работает. Тесты имеют плоскую структуру, никаких сьютов. В принципе, для моих задач может и хватить... У меня есть очень простая идея, как сделать удобно сьюты через массив, но я уже начал сомневаться, а надо ли... Если тестировать каждую функцию отдельно, то сьютом будет, фактически, каждый отдельный файл вида test_something.c. Их можно все компилировать и запускать программой на С или даже батником.

https://gist.github.com/vadimtukaev/11266857

Comment: @VadimTukaev, в 41-й строке

    #include "test.c"

это шутка такая?

Comment: абсолютно валидный код. #include просто вставляет файл. А то, что там расширение .с - это уже не препроцессора проблема. Компилятору на это также побоку - главное, что бы то, что получилось, скомпилировалось.

Такое даже практикуют в продакш коде. Только расширение inl обычно используют. И там внутри нормальный код, который бы в .с файл можно поместить (по логике).

Comment: @KoVadim, да просто сам файл, содержащий

    #include "test.c"

тоже называется `test.c` 

    // test.c

так в строке 1.

Что именно заинклюдит это валидный код?

Comment: @avp, там два файла описываются одним гистом. Комментарий "//" - это то, в каком файле лежит описываемое.