# Тесты: написания, структура, библиотеки, фреймворки

Tags: c, юнит-тесты

Есть ли в `C` фреймворки или библиотеки для тестирования, аналогичные тем, что есть, например в golang ([testing](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/), [goconvey](https://github.com/smartystreets/goconvey)), python ([pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/))?

Если таких нет, то каким образом в си принято организовывать и запускать тесты?

Comment: Огоо. Тестировать программы на С ты можешь только через отладку. Например, через gdb отладчик.

Comment: @Namous почему?

Comment: Ну, наверное, потому что этот язык относится с памятью очень строго, поэтому обычно программы на С отлаживают, так легче программистам отловить ошибки при выполнении.

Comment: @Namous Так как это связано с тестами? О_О

Comment: Вы спрашиваете про тестирование программ или про что?

Comment: Вы установили тег "юнит-тесты" (Изолированное исследование отдельных функциональных участков исходного кода программы на предмет их корректности, работоспособности, соответствия требованиям, отсутствия регрессий кода. Осуществляется путем написания и выполнения тестирующего кода.). gdb позволяет выполнять программу шаг за шагом.

Comment: @Namous всё верно. Почему Вы предлагаете мне использовать отладчик, вместо тестов, я так и не понял.

Comment: @Namous, напишите ответом ваши комментарии - я вам влеплю минус от всей души!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/315340/